# Bootstrap Modal Form Submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, form-submit

I have implemented a working Modal form using HTML, Bootstrap CSS and PHP, which displays information about a document. In the footer of the Modal I have a 'Delete Document' button which should post to the same page (index.php). The form doesn't react to the submit button.

Reading up on the subject a lot of people are using AJAX to submit from a Bootstrap Modal. This seems unnecessary? Do I really need to implement a JSON post in AJAX just to submit this Modal?

The code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="DocumentID" value="<?php echo $row['DocumentID']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="top-search" value="<?php echo $_POST['top-search']; ?>" />
        <button type="submit" name="deleteDocument" class="btn btn-w-m btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Document?')">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

I have an example where a Modal submits successfully although to a different page using a similar method but using target="_blank"

Comment: To come to the question "Do I really need to implement a JSON post in AJAX just to submit this Modal?" No you don't need to use AJAX or JSON. The reason to use AJAX is because the modal isn't going to be closed. The use of JSON is in my opinion depending on what you prefer. But what I have done in the past is just post the modal than when going back to the page with the modal. Load required results in modal then open modal with javascript. This way the modal isn't blank when opening

Comment: If the Modal doesn't close then the post hasn't successfully worked either? If I implement a JSON function, I just serialise the form data and post it to the relevant PHP page?

Comment: Maybe it's a good thing for you to watch some tutorials so you can see whats happening

Answer (score 0):

Its not onclick - but onClick.

Also, you need to place the scripts inside {}. The following code should work.

```
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div class="modal-footer">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="DocumentID" value="<?php echo $row['DocumentID']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="top-search" value="<?php echo $_POST['top-search']; ?>" />
        <button type="submit" name="deleteDocument" class="btn btn-w-m btn-danger" onClick={ function() {
      return confirm("Yes/No?");
    }}>Delete</button>
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>);
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not too sure what framework you are using there with the React Component. I am only using Bootstrap CSS and PHP for this current project.

Comment: You can use Bootstrap! I am using materialize (http://materializecss.com/) and tried React-material-which do not have enough Grid support).